# Using external image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm making simple application using turtle graphic library.

I tried to do .bgpic, But it seems doesn't walk as I wanted.

I putted the image at the same directory where python source file located, and I did like this:

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgpic("picture.png")
```

but It doesn't changes anything. When I run it, it has just white background.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image must be gif-file, [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgpic)

> **turtle.bgpic**(picname=None)
>
> **Parameters: picname** – a string, name of a gif-file or "nopic", or None
>
> Set background image or return name of
>   current backgroundimage. If picname is a filename, set the
>   corresponding image as background. If picname is "nopic", delete
>   background image, if present. If picname is None, return the filename
>   of the current backgroundimage.

**picture.gif**

[image]

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgpic("picture.gif")
turtle.done()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks fore your answer, but if i run same code at IDLE, it works.

Comment: @Central.Dogma Parameters: picname – a string, name of a gif-file or "nopic", or None

Comment: @Central.Dogma read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599311/tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-not-support-png-image