# how to add a png picture to a tinkter python window?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, png

i have a window and i am trying to add an image to it. the window so far consists of a label entry box and button. i want to add the image below the label but above the entry box button. Here is my code:

```
    master = Tk()
    master.wm_title("Lightning Parties")
    master.configure(background='lightgreen')
    Label(master, text="Staff Login", fg='black', bg='lightgreen', font=    ('comicsans', 14)).grid()
    Label(master, text="Please enter the password ", fg='black', bg='lightgreen', font=('comicsans', 12)).grid(row=7)

    Password= Entry(master)

    Password.grid(row=7, column=1)

    Button(master, text='Login', command=validateStaff, fg='black', bg='white', font=('comicsans', 12)).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

The image i want to add has the file name 'sonic.png'.

Comment: What problem are you having that can't be solved by reading available documentation? There are examples all over the internet showing how to add images to tkinter programs.

Comment: As @BryanOakley correctly stated, you should do some debugging at your own end once before posting on SO. Having said that have a look at these posts.

1. [tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-not-support-png-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599311/tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-not-support-png-image)

2. [how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter-python-2-7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter-python-2-7)

Comment: read tutorial or documentation: ie. [The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: @brenda Its not rude. Its just how SO works. Before you approach another person with a problem, you should do some digging at your end. Asking people for solutions without debugging is rather #rude! #NoOffense

Comment: i did debug it, and looked through documentation and i can't get my head around it. just because i don't dedicate my whole life to programming doesn't mean i should be disrespected and made to look stupid. we all struggle with different things, this is just my issue. SO is a place people go for help as a last resort. do you not think i have already spent hours trying to fix and research this myself? because for your information i did. if you have nothing nice to say don't say anything at all! #peaceout

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `PhotoImage` with the image you want, this will work for `.png`, `.gif` and lots of other image files.

Simply put your image in a `Label` and put the `Label` in the `grid`

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.wm_title("Lightning Parties")
master.configure(background='lightgreen')
Label(master, text="Staff Login", fg='black', bg='lightgreen', font=    ('comicsans', 14)).grid()
Label(master, text="Please enter the password ", fg='black', bg='lightgreen', font=('comicsans', 12)).grid(row=7)

Password= Entry(master)    
Password.grid(row=7, column=1)

my_image = PhotoImage(master = master, file = "Your_image.png") # your image
label = Label(master, image = my_image) # put the image on a label
label.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2) # put the label in the grid

Button(master, text='Login', command=validateStaff, fg='black', bg='white', font=('comicsans', 12)).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Also @Brenda the people commenting on your post are just trying to help you :) When I first joined SO some of my posts got down voted, you should learn from mistakes rather than being defensive :)

Comment: thanks, i tried this code but when i tried to run an error came up and said 'image "pyimage1" doesn't exist'. my image is called 'sonic' so i just changed the 'your_image.png' part of the code to 'sonic.gif'. any ideas where it has gone wrong? thanks again

Comment: is your image in the same folder as your Program? If not, that may be the cause of the error

Comment: I think the error saying that pyimage1 doesn't exist is because the image isn't linked to a master. Hopefully if you add `master = master` to the `PhotoImage` it should work