# Why does image fails to display in tkinter unless PhotoImage is saved as a variable?

Tags: python, image, variables, tkinter, photoimage

I just started learning python recently. I have tried to use Thonny. I googled and searched on stackoverflow such as [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function) and
[Tkinter.PhotoImage doesn't not support png image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599311/tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-not-support-png-image), but have not found similar questions yet... I have tried to read documentation, but am struggling.

**The image displays correctly when I saved the PhotoImage as a variable and then used canvas.create_image:**

```
tomato_img = PhotoImage(file="/Users/kwanh/PycharmProjects/day-28/tomato.png")

canvas.create_image(110, 112, image=tomato_img)
```

**However, when I did not save the PhotoImage as a variable, the image no longer displays:**

```
canvas.create_image(110, 112, image=PhotoImage(file="/Users/kwanh/PycharmProjects/day-28/tomato.png"))
```

I guess I can just save it as a variable but would like to know if it is because I have done something wrong? I used the type functions to check that the variable or without variable is of <class 'tkinter.PhotoImage'> Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/) could answer your question.

Comment: The `PhotoImage` in the second case exists only long enough for the `create_image()` call to complete. Apparently that's not long enough for it be displayed. I think the fact that tkinter doesn't increment the reference count of image objects which is what normally happens in Python code, and this is why saving in in a local variable often causes problems. This could happen if you put the first code inside a function, for example.

Comment: @martineau So not saving it as a variable was a problem because the image disappears too quickly as tkinter does not "increment the reference count of image". I have not tried using it in a function yet. Thank you for taking the time to explain in a way that I can understand!

Comment: @Atlas435 thanks for the interesting link about garbage collection. I understand more about how things work after reading it!