# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file PLEASE Solve For Windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried using a formatted code that already existed where I imported 'PIL' from 'ImageTk' however, that has not worked. The image and script is in the same file directory yet the image data is not recognizable. I changed the string to 'raw string' by adding the 'r' in front of the file path and I even tried using a different image and it still outputs the same error. This line ***linebackground_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\kevan\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming for me\Python\Tkinker\bgfortest.png')*** of the code is the source of error.

*Your help would be appreciated*

```py
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 700

WIDTH = 800

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)

canvas.pack()

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\kevan\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming for me\Python\Tkinker\bgfortest.png')

background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)

background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)

frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.75, anchor='n')

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Hello",  font=40)

button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg='white', font=40)

entry.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.65)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=10)

lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relheight=0.6, relwidth=0.75, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(lower_frame, text="This is a python GUI.", bg='cadet blue', fg="Black")

label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unrecognizable"?  Do you see an image that is garbage?  Is it the same image but resized?  Is it part of the image?

Comment: [tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-not-support-png-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599311/tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-not-support-png-image) may help.

Comment: @TimRoberts The image does not appear at all.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried the corrections from that initial script.

Comment: It may be your tk version because PNG is supported after version 8.6.  Or the image is not PNG actually.  You can try using `Pillow` module instead.