# TKINTER - Why is the window black

Tags: tkinter

Go easy on me. Why is my window black when I run this? It only started happening once I added the image using image=homepage, compound = bottom

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("420x420")
window.title("Owen First GUI program")

logo = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
window.iconphoto(True, logo)
window.config(background="white")

homepage = PhotoImage(file="homepage.png")

label = Label(window,
              text="Hello World",
              font=("Ariel", 40, "bold"),
              fg="#00FF00",
              bg="black",
              relief=RAISED,
              bd=10,
              padx=20,
              pady=20,
              image=homepage,
              compound="bottom")
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

IMAGES

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldap9.png)

[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37seA.png)

[BLACK SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6tn8.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the image?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Copy the image, click [edit], press ctrl+g

Comment: @Sujay I just added the image

Comment: Can you also include the image of the GUI created?

Comment: If you meant what I see then I just added it @Sujay

Comment: It works for me then. It is properly added, to the screen

Comment: strange, any clue why its not working for me?

Comment: @Sujay do you know why?

Comment: To be honest, no. I am using Windows 10. I have not idea why it is doing like that

Comment: I can't explain it, but I noticed it might be triggered by the `relief` option. The image appears if I set the relief to "flat", but turns black when I set the relief to "raised" or "sunken".

Comment: What platform are you on? I'm guessing OSX.

Comment: Try to convert your image to gif format. it works with me. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599311/tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-not-support-png-image>

Comment: @BryanOakley im on MacBook so yes. What would you recommend me doing, I've tried setting the format to .GIF but no luck

Comment: @MinhQuangNguyen Doesn't work with me. What operating system are you on?

Comment: You can try ttk.Label.

Answer (score 0):

it could be that the image is taking up the window's entire space

i suggest you use PhotoImage and SubSample:

```
Image = PhotoImage(file='photo.png')
Image = Image.subsample(3, 3)
```